# Check for internet connection in background

Tags: background, dart, connection, flutter, listen

This is like a really basic feature an application must perform.

The app has a queue of tasks pending and is waiting for the Internet to come online for execution.

Its easy to do this in foreground by using a stream subscription. But how would one achieve this when the app is closed?

Comment: What do you mean by "closed" ? Do you mean "in background" ?

Comment: @FlorentUguet the back button pressed in android or the home button in IOS. Yes I mean in background. Thats the title indeed.

Comment: What's the user case here? When the app is closed, what kind of tasks it should still perform tasks in the background?

Comment: @stt106 say.. perform some posts requests or notify the user that he is back online and must open the app for some task